# Exponential equation question

Tags: recreational-mathematics, exponential-sum

I've been trying to get my head around the following equation, I am doing this because I like doing maths, a friend of mine gave me these equations to tackle, I am no expert on exponential equations.
$$
    0.2^{2x-2} + 5 \cdot 0.04^{x+1} = 126
$$
I seem to be unable to get it, after trying with all I know, this one seems a bit too difficult and I would like to ask you for some help / explanation as to how I would tackle this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that $(0.2)^{2x}-2+5 \times (0.04)^{x}+1=126$?

Comment: The formatting of the exponent is ambiguous. Please use proper TeX formatting or at least paranthesis around the exponent.

Comment: Is my edit correct?

Comment: @S.C.B. the post has been edited to the right equation

Comment: It is @EmilioNovati Thank you

Comment: What is $0,04$? Is that $0.04$?

Comment: @S.C.B. it's **0.04**, typo on my end ^^

Comment: Hint. $0.2^{2A} =  ((0.2)^2) ^A$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

note that $0.04=0.2^2$. so you can write the equation as:
$$
0.04^{x-1}+5\times0.04^{x+1}=126
$$ 
Can you do from this?

Comment: It seems like this is going above my knowledge for now, like I said in my post, I'm doing this because I really like maths, but again, I think this is too far of a leap for now, I thank you for you time!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $0.04=0.2^2=5^{-2}$. Hence your equation is

$$0.04^{x-1}+5\cdot0.04^{x+1}=0.04^x(0.04^{-1}+5\cdot0.04)=126$$

or

$$5^{-2x}=5.$$

Comment: It seems like this is going above my knowledge for now, like I said in my post, I'm doing this because I really like maths, but again, I think this is too far of a leap for now, I thank you for you time!

Comment: @Simplicity: what are you missing in that resolution ?

Comment: The knowledge to get it, I seem to have overestimated myself

Comment: @Simplicity: a little short for an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I got a phonecall, so I pressed enter, I can't wrap my head around getting to x in this equation, I get that $0.04=0.2^2$ but I can't seem to get further at all, what do I do next, how do I get to x, like I said, I think I overestimated myself

Comment: @Simplicity: please spend time comparing the initial equation to the one I wrote and tell me what you are missing. This effort is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $0.2 = \tfrac{1}{5}$ and $0.04 = \tfrac{1}{25} = \left(\tfrac{1}{5}\right)^2$ and use this to transform everything to an easier base:
$$\left(\tfrac{1}{5}\right)^{2x-2}+5\left(\tfrac{1}{25}\right)^{x+1}
=\left(\tfrac{1}{5}\right)^{2x-2}+\left(\tfrac{1}{5}\right)^{2x+1}
=5^{-2x+2}+5^{-2x-1}=5^3 \cdot 5^{-2x-1}+5^{-2x-1}$$
Now you have:
$$5^3 \cdot 5^{-2x-1}+5^{-2x-1} = 126 \iff 5^{-2x-1} \left( 125+1 \right) = 126$$
So...